# Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$1

Tags: android, material-components-android

I have refactored my project to AndroidX and I have added material design after removing the support design library.
Here are my all dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    //implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"

    //implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'

    //implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'

   // implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'

    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'

    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.andremion:counterfab:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3'

    //implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'

    // Required only if Facebook login support is required

    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'

    //implementation 'com.github.DanielMartinus:Stepper-Touch:0.6'

    //implementation 'com.stone.vega.library:VegaLayoutManager:1.0.6'

    //implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'

    //implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    //implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    //implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'

    //implementation 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.1.0'

    //implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'

    //implementation'io.salyangoz.updateme:updateme:0.1.0'

    //implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.0'

    //implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'

    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.0'

    //implementation 'com.github.thomper:sweet-alert-dialog:v1.4.0'

    // Shimmer

    //implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'

    //implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'

    //implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.4'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.3'

    //implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug:4.13.1'

    //implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1-beta2"
    implementation 'com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:1.4.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

    //implementation 'com.yarolegovich:sliding-root-nav:1.1.0'
    implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1') {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

    //implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.2.0@aar') { transitive = true }
}
```

I think I am having two dependencies which have the same component. But I am not able to figure out which one.
The AppBarLayout component is in two libraries.

Comment: could you please execute androidDependencies task and past the result?

Comment: Hey @AnisBENNSIR can you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: ./gradlew :app:androidDependencies

Comment: Hey @AnisBENNSIR after running ./gradlew :app:androidDependencies it is saying that "Could not be able to find google-services.json file in src/nullnull/debug"  but this is not the reason for this error. it is just a warning.

Comment: Could you please past the output for Android dependencies task?

Comment: This error has been solved now. I was not updating the material theme in style-21.